# Draw smooth line graph with high performance

Tags: android, canvas, charts, rendering, linegraph

I need to draw line graph with lakes of points in canvas rendering. I used following ways to optimize the performance,

1. Avoided to create object in onDraw method.
2. Using drawLines method in canvas rather than using path.moveTo and path.lineTo, since, my thought is path is always render using CPU not GPU.
3. Removed line anti-alias.
4. Not set alpha value for line color.
5. Set HardwareAcceleration to true.
6. Using some sampling algorithms.

This is what i actually doing after read some performance tips to get good performance, If you know to make even better please suggest to me.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of drawLine you can use drawRect. And use SurfaceView. (Quite honestly, I don't like SurfaceView for some limitations it has and organise back buffers myself, but most of developers prefer it).

This is what comes to my mind (without testing and thinking much).

Suppose you have a table grpData[] of float data, each in range 0f to 1f.  You also have a table of colours (not colour resource Ids) grpColours.

Them your code will look smth like this:

```
private Paint p = new Paint();

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  super.onDraw(canvas);      // Draws background

  int width = getWidth();
  int height = getHeight();
  int count = grpData.length;
  float xStep = (float) width / count;

  float x=0f; 

   for (int i=0; i<count, i++) {
      float nextX = x+xStep;
      p.setColor(grpColours[i]);
      canvas.drawRect(x, (1f-grpData[i])*height, nextX, height, p);
      x = nextX;
  }

}
```

PS. I am not sure that hardware acceleration really helps. On the contrary it may cause problems with some cheap devices.